# UITableView Scrolling Performance with Custom UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview

Requirement : To Display upto 9 Datapoints in a single Custom TableViewCell with 2 `UILabels`,4 `UIButtons` and 3 `UIImages`.

Problem Statement:Scrolling with the Custom `UITableViewCell` is not smooth with these `UIImages` and `UIButtons` added as subviews. There are approximately 500 rows in the `UITableView`.

Comment: Are the images being fetched from a server to display?

Comment: All Images are dynamically added depending on data from the server.All the Images are locally stored.

Comment: The problem is with the images, but you should provide more info where you are fetching images from

Comment: Can you try downloading the required images first and then reload the tableView or you can use SDWebImage for downloading the images.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is in number of view on one cell.
Try to set shouldRasterize property of cell's layer to YES.

```
yourCell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
yourCell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

But remember that all animated views such as UIActivityIndicatorView will force the cell to redraw it's content on each frame.

Answer (score 0):

I use this Library which is just perfect

- [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

You just need to `#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>` to your project, and you can define also the placeholder when image is being downloaded with just this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";
    return cell;
}
```

It also cache downloaded images and gives you great performance.

Hope it will help you!